# UPS API - printing the returned shipping label GIF data

Tags: xml, gif, ups

So I'm working my way through the UPS API 'create shipping label' process...I'm at the final stage, where having validated everything, UPS return the actual shipping label to me in GIF format, from their example document, here's what is returned via XML (I've edited out all the other preceding XML bits)..

```
<GraphicImage>FSDJHSDJHJ3487EHNE9U8DY9VHRFV89SDFHFSDJHFSDIDFH
SJKDFSJKDFSJIU9GFIUGJIFDUJG9UKGLDJFDKJDGKJDFKGDJLDFKSJGKDFJDKGFDG9E0ER
IJGE39IWURE9U9ER0UW9R0UR9WEGU9URE9WGUW90U90GRUG90GERUG9REUGWERGJIO
JGIODFGUIOFDUGIOFUIGRUE090U9TERUT90RUT9EU90ERUT9ERU9EUER9TUT9R0UTE90R
U9TERU90RTEU9SDKHGJHGDFU</GraphicImage>
<HTMLImage>SKJJKLHGIGKHGKJHGFJGFJHDFJGHDDJFHFDJHFJHFJKDHJK
FDHJFJDFHDFJHJDFHGJDHGDFSHJKFSDHSDFJHFJSDHJKDFHFJKSHDSKJHGFDJSJDFSKSK
JJKLHGIGKHGKJHGFJGFJHDFJGHDDJFHFDJHFJHFJKDHJKFDHJFJDFHDFJHJDFHGJDHGDF
SHJKFSDHSDFJHFJSDHJKDFHFJKSHDSKJHGFDJSJDFSKHGJKDS</HTMLImage>
```

..what am I meant to do with either that GIF  data or that HTMLIMage data? For example I piped the GIF data into a gif file - but the GIF file won't open - is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

Most shipping API's return labels as Base 64 encoded strings (in JSON or XML).
You'll need to convert the content from base 64 to an bite array, and save it.

The way you do the Base64 conversion varies by development platform, but there are plenty of examples. Here's one I just found.

http://processrhetoric.blogspot.com/2013/01/getting-ups-shipping-label-via-their-api.html

If you use the Google Chrome browser, you can preview the image by building a string that starts with

```
data:image/gif;base64,
```

Then add the image content (though your example content doesn't seem to work).

```
data:image/gif;base64,FSDJHSDJHJ3487EHNE9U8DY9VHRFV89SDFHFSDJHFSDIDFH
SJKDFSJKDFSJIU9GFIUGJIFDUJG9UKGLDJFDKJDGKJDFKGDJLDFKSJGKDFJDKGFDG9E0ER
IJGE39IWURE9U9ER0UW9R0UR9WEGU9URE9WGUW90U90GRUG90GERUG9REUGWERGJIO
JGIODFGUIOFDUGIOFUIGRUE090U9TERUT90RUT9EU90ERUT9ERU9EUER9TUT9R0UTE90R
U9TERU90RTEU9SDKHGJHGDFU
```

And put the results in the browser address bar, and the image will appear.

In JavaScript / VBScript, use ADODB to save the bytes that you create from base64 to disk as a GIF.

```
var stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
try {
    if (objFSO.FileExists(strFileName)) {
        objFSO.DeleteFile(strFileName);
    }
    stream.Type = 2; // text
    stream.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
    stream.Open();
    stream.WriteText(bytes);
    stream.SaveToFile( strFileName, 2);
} catch (err){
    return;
} finally {
    if (stream.State != 0) {
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that was it ....I found a base64 decoder & can now view the GIF file ...I'm doing alll this in VBA so wondered if there's a way of simply opening up the decoded GIF data in a browser via access...

Comment: See updates with ADO (I only have a javascript example).

Comment: Thanks william...in the end I managed to sort this...a combination of...1, Base64 decoding, 2. Image rotation (for some reason UPS send you their shipping label on it's side) & 3. cropping (for some reason UPS adds 200 pixels of white space at the foot of their downloaded label...this messes up the ratios. I did some googling & managed to address/remedy all these issues within VBA. Thanks for your input in my hour of need :-)

Comment: Glad it worked out. BTW, I work for up-voted answers : )

Answer (score 1):

```
For this we need two gems:
gem "wicked_pdf"
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'


ups_gif_image =  base64 GIF image # This is the 
base64 graphicimage in the form of GIF that is returned from UPS 
shipment request API  

ups_base64_gif_image ="data:image/gif;base64,"+ups_gif_image
pdf_data = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string("<img src='"+ups_base64_gif_image+"'/>",{:orientation => 'Landscape'})
File.open('label.pdf','wb') do |pdf|
  pdf.write pdf_data
  pdf.close
end
```