# get label back from UPS API call

Tags: ups

Is anyone familiar with the API sample code for UPS web service DOTNET, I'm testing the code sample from the UPS API, ShipWSSample. I am getting a tracking number back but not sure how to get the label data from the ShipmentResponse. The code has referenced label code just above where I get the response.

```
    Dim labelSpec As New LabelSpecificationType()
    Dim labelStockSize As New LabelStockSizeType()
    labelStockSize.Height = "6"
    labelStockSize.Width = "4"
    labelSpec.LabelStockSize = labelStockSize
    Dim labelImageFormat As New LabelImageFormatType()
    labelImageFormat.Code = "GIF"
    labelSpec.LabelImageFormat = labelImageFormat

    shipmentRequest.Shipment = shipment
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = DirectCast(3072,   SecurityProtocolType)
    Dim shipmentResponse As ShipmentResponse = shpSvc.ProcessShipment(shipmentRequest)
```

Any help would be appreciated
Mike

Comment: I found a post on here that answers my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986453/ups-api-printing-the-returned-shipping-label-gif-data